# ambiguity of "supply"

Tags: meaning

an example from [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/diminish):
**(1)** *Our **supplies** are diminishing rapidly*.

I think (1) has three meanings:
**(1A)** The things we have are diminishing rapidly.
**(1B)** The things we get are diminishing rapidly.
**(1C)** The things we give are diminishing rapidly.

Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

an example from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/supply_2) (inside the block "Extra Examples"):
**(2)** *Local schools **supply** many of the volunteers*.

I think (2) has two meanings:
**(2A)** Local schools give somebody many of the volunteers.
**(2B)** Local schools give something to many of the volunteers.

Am I right?
If not, then why not?

Comment: ***supplies*** means ***things which are supplied*** - almost always with the strong implication ***...on a regular basis***. So only **1B** really makes sense for the first example. **1A** should be ***reserves***, because the obvious likely context is one where the supply chain itself has ceased to operate. And **1C** is just the wrong way of expressing the fact that ***our*** supplies (of the things we supply to others further down the chain) are diminishing.

Answer (score 4):

Only 1A is a natural interpretation.  *Supplies* is clearly a noun here, and "our supplies" just means "the things that we have".  The sentence says nothing about whether we give these things to others or get them from others, but because [the definition of *supplies*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/supplies) is

> food and other ordinary goods needed by people every day

the only natural interpretation is that these are goods that *we* need, because they are *our supplies*.

---

Both 2A and 2B are possible interpretations.  I think 2A is a more natural interpretation; *we supply X*, without any further explanation, usually means that we are a source of X.  If 2B was intended, a more natural phrasing is *supply X with Y*, like "Local schools supply many of the volunteers **with (whatever it is they need)**".

Comment: Do you think "_direct supplies_" is incorrect? Because if it's correct, then the noun "_supplies_" in "_direct supplies_" means "_the things we get or give_".

Comment: @Loviii  It depends on the context of "direct supplies".  I'm not sure why you say *supplies* means "the things we get or give"; the definition of supplies doesn't include anything about giving or receiving.  (Maybe you collected them yourself, for example.)